# Rotate pdf object using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, web

I have a pdf embedded inside an html.

```
<object id="img" height="540" width="100%" type='application/pdf' data="http://file.pdf" />
```

I need to rotate it using javascript (or jquery)
something like `$("img").rotate(90);`

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$("#img").css({'transform':'rotate(90deg)',
    '-o-transform': 'rotate(90deg)',
    '-ms-transform': 'rotate(90deg)',
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(90deg)'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css transform property http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

```
#img {
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: not a good soultion, since it will also turn the menu.i am looking for pdf api that will turn the page.